# Sprite-Kit: color xor logic with two sprites. black + black = white

Tags: ios, colors, sprite-kit, xor

Do you know the puzzle game „voi“? That is a game which works with color-XOR-logic. That means: black + black = white.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw5BdVcAtII

Is there any way to do the same color logic with two sprite nodes in sprit kit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it's possible to do that in Sprite Kit.

**Problem:**

Let's say you have 2 black squares, `squareA` and `squareB`. The user can drag these two squares wherever he wants to. He can drag only one square at a time. You want to color the intersect area to white whenever the two squares intersect.

**Initial Setup:**

At the top of your scene, there are a few variables that we need to create:

```
private var squareA: SKSpriteNode?
private var squareB: SKSpriteNode?
private var squares = [SKSpriteNode]()
private var selectedShape: SKSpriteNode?
private var intersectionSquare: SKShapeNode?
```

- `squareA` and `squareB` are just the 2 squares that we initially have on screen.
- `squares` is an array and it will store all the squares that are showing on screen.
- `selectedShape` will help us keeping track of the square that is currently being dragged.
- `intersectionSquare` is a white square that represents the intersection area between the two black squares.

Then initialize `squareA` and `squareB`, and add them to the `squares` array like so:

```
    squareA = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 190.0, height: 190.0))

    if let squareA = self.squareA {
        squareA.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: 200)
        squareA.name = "Square A"
        squares.append(squareA)
        self.addChild(squareA)
    }

    // Do the same for squareB or any other squares that you have on screen..
```

*Note: As you can see, I gave it a name here just to make it easier to differentiate them during the testing phase.*

**Detect when user is dragging a square:**

Now, you need to detect when the user is dragging a square. To do this, you can use:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }
```

These are just helper methods that are going to make our life easier.

Then, you need to setup `touchDown`, `touchMoved` and `touchUp` methods:

```
 func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

        let touchedNode = self.nodes(at: pos)

        guard let selectedSquare = touchedNode.first as? SKSpriteNode else {
            return
        }

        selectedShape = selectedSquare
    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

        guard let selectedSquare = self.selectedShape else {
            return
        }

        selectedSquare.position = pos

        checkIntersectionsWith(selectedSquare)
    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        selectedShape = nil
    }
```

To explain you in more details what is going on here:

- In the `touchDown` method:

Well, we need the user to be able to drag only one square at a time. Using the `nodes(at:)` method, it's easy to know which square was touched, and we can know set our `selectedShape` variable to be equal to the square that was touched.

- In the `touchMoved` method:

Here we are basically just moving the `selectedShape` to the position the user moves his finger at. We also call the `checkIntersectionsWith()` method that we will setup in a second.

- In the `touchUp` method:

The user released his finger from the screen, so we can set the `selectedShape` to nil.

**Change the color of the intersection frame:**

Now the most important part to make your game actually look like the one you want to make, is how to change the color of the intersection frame to white when two black squares are intersecting ?

Well, you have different possibilities here, and here is one possible way of doing it:

```
private func checkIntersectionsWith(_ selectedSquare: SKSpriteNode) {

    for square in squares {

        if selectedSquare != square && square.intersects(selectedSquare) {

            let intersectionFrame = square.frame.intersection(selectedSquare.frame)

            intersectionSquare?.removeFromParent()
            intersectionSquare = nil

            intersectionSquare = SKShapeNode(rect: intersectionFrame)

            guard let interSquare = self.intersectionSquare else {
                return
            }

            interSquare.fillColor = .white
            interSquare.strokeColor = .clear
            self.addChild(interSquare)

        }  else if selectedSquare != square {

            intersectionSquare?.removeFromParent()
            intersectionSquare = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the `checkIntersectionsWith()` method is called, we are iterating through the nodes that are inside our `squares` array, and we check, using the frame's `intersection()` method, if the selected square intersects with any of these (except itself). If it does, then we create a white square, named `intersectionSquare`, and set its frame to be equal to the intersection frame.

And to save up your memory usage, you can delete the square from the scene and set `intersectionSquare` to `nil` if there is no intersection at all.

**Final result:**

The final result would look like this:

[image]

That's just a rapid draft that I made to show you on you could approach the problem, and obviously there are many things that you could add or improve (apply this to a situation where you have not only 2 but many squares on screen, or create a kind of magnetism effect for when your user release his finger from the screen, etc) but I hope at least it will put you on the right track for your project :)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much